# How to integrate a WebCam RTSP Stream in a .Net Blazor Video HTML Tag

Tags: html, .net, video, blazor, rtsp

We have a [SPE-400](https://product.hanwha-security.com/en-sea/products/peripherals/encoder/A/SPE-400/overview/?strzYn=1) Video Encoder Box on which 3 video signals are connected to.
The SPE-400 Box sends an RTSP Stream.

How can I display this RTSP Stream in a Video HTML 5 Tag on a .Net Blazor Application?
It seems that the video tag cannot handle an RTSP stream.

Any ideas or suggestions out there?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Full disclaimer-- I'm not an expert.  I know streamers sometimes use RTSP for live broadcast, including on YouTube.  So you could try running it through YouTube and then embedding a YouTube player on your site.  If  you have access to a server, you could find some library and transcode it on your own.  Or you could try to find a Javascript RTSP library and do it in Javascript.

It has absolutely nothing to do with Blazor.

Comment: These are private WebCams and the whole solution should work on the local network. I have managed it with UMediaServer service http://www.umediaserver.net/ but I find it very cumbersome and the question is if there is nothing better to display RTSP in HTML5 video tag.

Comment: If it's all local, then you should dedicate a machine on your server to translating the RTSP to another form and rebroadcasting it in a more web-friendly format.  There are a LOT of programs that you might look into, but I'd start with OBS. I think you'll likely need a player of some type for the RTMP (or whatever) stream.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973
Thanks for your answer. As I wrote, now I use the windows Service Unreal Media Server to convert from RTSP to WebRTC and with a JavaScript Code (Code comes from umediaserver.net) I'm able to display my WebCam Stream onto a Video Tag in my HTML Page. My question was if there are easier ways to do this. it seems complicated and many steps until this works. You speak about OBS, do you mean https://obsproject.com/ ? I don’t know this tool. Is this like Unreal Media Server a kind of Service which translate the stream from one to another format?